# Testing a stop engine solenoid

Tags: relay

Desired outcome is 0 Ω.
When testing the solenoid the reading is 0 Ω to start, then immediately 16.1 Ω.
When I repeat the test the readings are the same.

Why does the reading change?

Comment: Is your multimeter an **auto-ranging** type? It may by default avoid the lower scales to conserve battery power. When first connected, it is on a higher scale (which shows a low reading), then auto-scales to a more sensitive scale.

Comment: Thank you, meter is more sophisticated than me. I was unaware of the function of "auto" so now it reads a 0.0 ohm

Comment: So is the 9v meter powering the solenoid enough to give me a reading of 16.1 ohms?

Comment: Yes. the internal battery supplies a *very small* current to the solenoid to make an ohm measurement. Not nearly enough to move the solenoid. Some poor auto-ranging ohmmeters are not so smart...sometimes they cannot decide which range to use, and switch back and forth between two ranges, and you are unable to get a reading. i